# Session parse from django templae

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got this in my django template.

```
{{request.session[0]}}
```

And I got this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'request.session[0]'
```

When I used `{{request.session}}` in the template also shows the object hash so I guess the data passing is ok and  when I can print session[0] without any trouble then why it would it possibly not work at template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to array elements with `.` in templates :

```
{{request.session.0}}
```

from [wiki](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) :

> Dot lookups can be summarized like this: when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

```
Dictionary lookup (e.g., foo["bar"])
Attribute lookup (e.g., foo.bar)
Method call (e.g., foo.bar())
List-index lookup (e.g., foo[2])
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I will need to wait 11 more minute to accept the answer!